# Data deletion using jQuery AJAX not working on Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement a table with some data and a delete button to delete that particular data. The code doesn't seem to be working:
**Model**:menu.php 
**Controller**: Admin.php
**Table**:menu_items

```
<table id='all_items_menu' class='table-hover table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped'>  <br>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Category</th>
    <th>Item Type</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>    
<?php foreach($items as $i) { ?>    
<tr>                            
    <td><?php echo $i->index; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $i->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $i->item_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $i->item_category; ?></td>
    <td><p style='color:green'><b><?php echo $i->type; ?></b></p></td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group btn-sm'>
            <button class='btn btn-info'>Update</button>
            <button  id="<?php echo $i->index; ?>" class='btn btn-danger delete_item'>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

The JS code:

```
$('.delete_item').click(function(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")){     
      var index = $(this).attr('id');
      var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
      $.ajax(
       {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Stryker/index.php/Admin/delete_menu_items",
        data: 'index='+index,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){            
          try{    
            if(response=='true'){
              parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
            }               
          }catch(e) {   
            alert('Exception while request..');
          }   
        },
        error: function(){            
         alert('Error while request..');
        }
      });        
    }
});
```

The Controller funcion delete_menu_items() is as follows

```
public function delete_menu_item(){
    $index = $this->input->post('index');
    $query = $this->menu->delete_item($index);
    $status = "false";
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        $status = "true";
    }
    echo $status;
}
```

And finally, the code for function delete_item in the model menu.php:

```
function delete_item($index){
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM menu_items WHERE index =?';
    $this->db->query($sql,array($index)); 
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

I have autoloaded all the models and required helpers. I get an alert box with the text "Error while request..". Kindly point out the mistake in the code or procedure.

Comment: Your first mistake is not using proper error handling. `Error while request..` doesn't give you any information, right? Use this in your error callback: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log('Status: ' + textStatus, 'Error: ' + errorThrown); }` And see what is logged.

Answer (score 0):

In $.ajax pass data like this

```
data: {index:index},
```